# How can I show a mathematical proof of entropy in clasification tree?

Tags: cart, entropy, gini

I am trying to understand the splitting criteria in the classification tree. How can I show that for $p_1,p_2,..,p_n$ these functions attaining their maximum and minimum?

$g(p_1,p_2,...,p_n) = Σp_i(1-p_i)$

$h(p_1,p_2,...,p_n) = -Σp_i log p_i$

Comment: What is n here?

Comment: I edit the post. Maybe you can see it better. This is just to show that is for every p

Comment: Because these functions are defined on the simplex ($\sum p_i=1,$ all $p_i$ in the interval $[0,1]$) and are continuous, [they attain both their maxima and minima.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem)  The proof is a question of pure mathematics.  But I suspect that's not what you meant to ask.  What was your intended question?